# Run testng tests successively on parallel machines

Tags: maven, testng, selenium-grid

I have following configuration for webtesting with selenium:
eclipse+maven+testng, selenium grid with 2 nodes.
1st node: ie10 + firefox; 2nd node: ie11+chrome.
I need to execute tests successively for node, but in parallel for nodes. Current configuration starts two methods for two nodes. Is it possible to reconfigure testng and maven to follow my needs? I have no possibility to start 4 machine for each browser, only 2.
Here is my testng xml

```
<suite name="Test Suite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests">
<test name="Tests - ie10">
    <parameter  name="browser" value="ie10"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
<test name="Tests - chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
<test name="Tests - firefox">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
<test name="Tests - ie11">
    <parameter name="browser" value="ie11"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
```

and maven plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.16</version>
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>target/test-classes/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
        <browser>${browser}</browser>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>listener</name>
            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
    <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create 2 suite files - add that to 1 suite file.  In one suite file
put

```
<suite name="Test Suite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests">
<test name="Tests - ie10">
    <parameter  name="browser" value="ie10"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
<test name="Tests - chrome">
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="TestExportConfiguration"></class>
    </classes>      
</test>
```

In another put the other ones with firefox and ie11 with parallel=tests.
Add both these suite files to one suite file.

Comment: Exactly! And so simple, how I missed this... Thank you!